# Program, time schedule sounds (mp3, wav)

Tags: 14.04, sound, schedule

Im looking for a program which play certain sounds that I add - in the program - on different times. Have googled a lot but haven't found anything.

Have a great day!

Comment: Could you tell a bit more about the context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try kalarm. It can do what you ask and much more. http://www.astrojar.org.uk/kalarm/index.html

Comment: Super! That was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.